# Can I pass the Invoke method on a form to another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

Bit of a confusing architectural problem.

I have a form, called `MyForm`, and it has a textbox on it that I want to log to. There is a `Output(string, LogType)` method that does this. LogType is an enum.

I have a `Manager` class, which when created, spawns a thread. I want that thread to add to the textbox.

I want to do it in the most abstract way possible.

Ideally, this would involve passing a reference to the `Invoke` method on the form,  with a Delegate pointing to my `Log(string)` method, such that the Manager class is simply handed an object, and it can do `object("hello")`

I'm not actually sure however if this is possible. I got tied up in delegates and lambdas and actions trying to figure it out.

It would be elegant as I wouldn't have to add any extra methods to my form or write log wrapper or anything. Is it possible?

Edito: I've come up with this, I might be close:

`new Action<string, LogType>((s,l) => Invoke(new Action<string, LogType>((t,m) => Output(t,m))));`

then I need to pass the s,l into t,m

`new Action<string, LogType>((s,l) => Invoke(new Action<string, LogType>((t,m) => Output(t,m))(s,l)));`

and then it goes all wrong

Seems a bit long winded though...

Comment: Why don't you just use `Invoke` within the `Log` method of your MyForm?

Comment: The `Invoke` method calls another method, so I'd have to have two log methods, I think

Comment: Don't.  That other class is supposed to copy SynchronizationContext.Current in its constructor.  Its Send() method uses Invoke, Post() uses BeginInvoke.  If that code updates UI then it should raise an event instead, so the form can select the proper control to update.  Loggers should be thread-safe btw, hard to tell what the code is trying to do

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Send() and Post()? Invoke would work, for example if I hardcoded passing in the form, but I am hoping for a nicer solution

Comment: 30 seconds probably wasn't enough to look at the SynchronizationContext class.  You have to look.

Comment: The code already works if I just pass in `frmMyForm`  , and do `.Invoke(new Action(() => Invoke(frmMyForm.Output("Hello", ..))`, I am just trying to move the `Invoke` part out so I don't need to pass the actual form in. It's not a question of threading and contexts, just of delegates. You could forget threading altogether and just pretend I have two methods, and I want to pass in a method that calls method2 into an external object.

Answer (score 0):

If your `MyForm` class creates the `Manager` object, you could pass to the `Manager` constructor a delegate that will let it use the `Output` method:

**`MyForm.cs`**

```cs
Manager m = new Manager(Output);

private void Output(string s, LogType t) { }
```

and in your `Manager` class:

**`Manager.cs`**

```cs
private Action<string, LogType> _logAction;

public Manager(Action<string, LogType> logAction) { 
    _logAction = logAction;
}

private void DoStuff() {
    logAction("My log message", LogType.Info);
}
```

**Note that you might run into problems due to the fact that UI objects cannot be modified outside from the UI thread.**

There are better ways to handle logging to the UI, like `MyForm` subscribing to an event of `Manager`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, however instead of just passing in Output, I want to pass in `Invoke` which is calling `Output()`, because then it will be thread safe. I can't figure that part out though.